# JcomboBox has no border?

Tags: java, networking

When my program starts up, the comboboxes (there are 2 that are having this problem) do show up.  However, when I click on the arrow one item (there should be 7 items showing) shows up and there is no border around the list.  If I drag my mouse over the area all the other items appear, but still no border.
This is only happening at our warehouse which is about 400 yards from the main office.  We have fiber going over there and are on the same LAN.  I'm not sure if this is a network issue or a java issue.
Any help is very much appreciated.

Chris

Comment: What version of Java are you developing on, and what version is the warehouse running?

Comment: Some kind of timing issue aggravated by increased latency? Usual question: Are you doing all your Swing work from the AWT Event Dispatch Thread (EDT)?

Comment: Developing with 1.4.2_18 and they are using 1.4.2_15.  I thought that may be causing the problem but the program runs fine in the main office with 1.4.2_15.

Comment: You need to give us more information.  Code snippets?

Comment: Sorry, most of the code for this is 3rd party and I do not have access to it, making things extremely difficult/frustrating.

Answer (score 0):

I remotely logged into the computer this morning to try this out for myself, with different versions of the package (one that was built using 1.4.1_18 and one with 1.4.1_15).  Turns out that if I minimized the program and then maximized it, everything was fine (using both versions).
I commented out `setExtendedState(getExtendedState() | MAXIMIZED_BOTH)` which comes after everything is initialized for the frame.  Rebuilt, restarted and the borders are there along with all the items, so it now works perfectly.

Does anyone know why this would be causing a problem?